# Error accessing an Azure Active Directory secured resource

Tags: azure

I need to access a Web API which is secured via Azure Active Directory. I followed this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

The first steps were successful, but at the end I can't access the required resource.

What I did:

First I call this link

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3eec...32e5
```

and get redirected to the login portal.

After successful login I extract the code from redirected URL, which is something like this

```
https://localhost:8080/?code=AAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27........RdzFpearqiAA
```

Then I use this code to acquire an access token. The first problem is here. According to the documentation (link above) the resource is optional. But it doesn't work if I omit the resource (error=Resource identifier is not provided.), so I have to provide it. Secondly, if I put the APP ID URI of my application registered in Azure AD to the recourse parameter, I got another error ( The client '3eec...32e5' and resource 'myapp.azurewebsites.net' identify the same application.). Therefore I put the graph.windows.net for resource parameter.

```
 curl -s -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/akeliusdev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token 
 -d grant_type=authorization_code -d client_id=3eec...32e5 
 -d client_secret=F%2BfpjpR............Wi8%3D 
 -d code=AAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27........RdzFpearqiAA -d resource=https://graph.windows.net
```

This way I could get an access token. But then I am not able to access the resource using the access token. I did it this way:

```
 curl https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/data 
 --header "Authorization:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ.............4WYr6xn"
```

Could someone help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this as a service to service call, without user interaction, you can follow [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx)

You need to create an AAD application and credentials. i.e. a Service Principal.

then to get the access token you make a POST call to

`https://login.windows.net/<tenant ID>/oauth2/token`

with the following data

`grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$username&client_secret=$password&resource=$resource`

Where $username is your `HTTP://localhost/whatever` identifier

$password is your service principal password

$resource is `https://management.core.windows.net/` (this might be graph, try it and see)

The access token will be in the JSON response as 'access_token'

You then add a header of `Authorization: Bearer $AccessToken` and hopefully you should get access!

Comment: Actually this solution is not what I am looking for. I need to get the users the ability to login with their own username/pwd.

Comment: @ArashTaheri My apologies, it seems I misread / went stupid! - I will amend the answer to state that it is service to service, incase anyone else needs it in future

Comment: Anyhow I appreciate your commitment :)